# Displaying Top 3 Customers and Amounts in ListBox From TextFile

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm looking to display the top three customers and their total amounts from a textfile in the listbox/listview when the form is loaded, I was wondering if this is possible using arrays? There are multiple figures in the textfile including other inital investment amounts, interest amounts. So i need it to find just the total amount and the top 3 customers names.

So far I've tried this and it doesn't work,Would listbox or listview work better and should there be another way i should be trying it? so i was wondering if you could help me with this? Thanks :)

```
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("transactions.txt"))

   {

listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader { Width = listView1.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth });

 int[] array = new int[] {};
 int[] largest = array
                .OrderByDescending(item => item)
                .Take(array.Length).ToArray();}

   //Here is the code for the transactions.txt file and what it contains.
             public void CreateFile()
{
     StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("transactions.txt");
        outputFile.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("");
        outputFile.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has incomplete(maybe incorrect). If you want to find first top 3 you should use

`array.OrderByDescending(item => item).Take(3)`

and I'm not find what is

```
listView1.View = View.Details; listView1.HeaderStyle =
ColumnHeaderStyle.None; listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader { Width
= listView1.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth });
```

foreach line in text you add column. ?!?

Comment: Yeah thats adding a column for each line :)

Comment: What is result for take(3)? You needed some aggregate for total. Where was that, and why you think result is not corrected.

Comment: its not appearing in the viewbox